# How to fit and evaluate tf.data.dataset with tf.keras at the end of every epoch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

When x is `tf.data` dataset, a tuple of `(inputs, targets)` and inputs is a dict of features like `{"fea_1": val_1, "fea_2": val_2…}`, `model.fit` function in `tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py` doesn't support `validation_data` or `validation_split`.

`validation_split` is not supported when x is a dataset. `validation_data` only supported Numpy arrays or tensors.

I can `take` or `split` dataset to`model.fit` and `model.evaluate`, but it cannot perform validation at the end of every epoch.

Is there a better way to train and evaluate `tf.data.dataset` when input features is a dict?

Comment: You can provide `tf.data.Dataset` object to `model.fit()` method with the `validation_data=` argument. You need to specify the batch size though.

Comment: `validation_data` param only supported numpy arrays or tensors. The feature in my dataset is a dict, and every features is a numpy array to used in different input layers.

Comment: `validation_data` argument does support tf.data.Dataset. See the documentation

Comment: I' ve looked around. It's sad that my feature is a dict not a array: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L545

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Really......? What is the supporting link??

Answer (score 0):

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)
```

Just convert the

> tf.data.Dataset (Mine were **Python Lists**)

to

> Numpy.array

and it will work **Great**

Comment: All this results in is an array of length 1. `[<_LoadDataset shapes: <unknown>, types: tf.int64>]`